# Email verification firebase React Native Expo Go

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, email-verification

I have been building using firebase, expo and expo go. I want to redirect a user to the app once authentication is done. Is that possible using React Native expo?

Comment: You can use firebase Dynamic Links to redirect from email to your app.

Comment: I understand from the docs that firebase deep linking does not work with expo go and expo apps. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/ So does that mean that the dynamic link will not open the app ?

Comment: Technically this possible with Universal Linking - https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-universal-link-in-expo-using-firebase-dynamic-link-7c70eba737c2